# How to find cell in table and set that found cell's next cell's value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm having hard time trying to set certain cell's value in table.

Here is link to jsfiddle with contains a sample of this: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/EGm3v/)

I have table, which is created in following way:

```
var r = [];
var j = -1; 
r[++j] =  '<table cellspacing="0" id="TableWeeklyFrame"><thead><tr><th><div>Day</div></th><th><div>Profile</div></th></tr></thead><tbody>'; 
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {     
    r[++j] = '<tr class="WeeklyFrameTR">';
    r[++j] = '<td class="WeeklyFrameDay">';
    r[++j] = data[i];
    r[++j] = '</td><td><select class="SelectionWeeklyFrameProfile"></select>';
    r[++j] = '</td>';
    r[++j] = '</tr>';
}
r[++j] = '</tbody></table>';
$('#TableWeeklyFrame').html(r.join(''));
```

So table has 7 rows and 2 columns:

```
|Day|Profile|
|Monday|Value|
|Tuesday|Value|
|Wednesday|Value|
|Thursday|Value|
|Friday|Value|
|Saturday|Value|
|Sunday|Value|
```

Value is a selection containing several values.

Now the problem..

I have a set of values, e.q. (day=Monday,value=Off). Since days aren't always in that order (well most are but that's not the point here) I need to first find the row which contains the day and then set the value of selection to whatever I want.

I can find the row which has the certain day by doing

```
$('#TableWeeklyFrame tr.WeeklyFrameTR').find('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")');
```

And finally the question: How can I set the next/second cell's value of that row?

I'm trying not to loop through the whole table. So far I have tried several things, including:

```
$('#TableWeeklyFrame tr.WeeklyFrameTR').find('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")').find('td select.SelectionWeeklyFrameProfile').val()
$('#TableWeeklyFrame tr.WeeklyFrameTR').find('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")').next('td').val()
$('#TableWeeklyFrame tr.WeeklyFrameTR').find('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")').find('select.SelectionWeeklyFrameProfile').val() 
$('#TableWeeklyFrame tr.WeeklyFrameTR').find('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")').next('select.SelectionWeeklyFrameProfile').val()
```

They all return undefined. I'm missing something here and I have a feeling it's something stupid and small..

Also, if there's a simpler and faster way of achieving similar result, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this in a simpler way by going through the parent:

```
$('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")').parent().find('select')
```

Overall, I think this solution of moving around the dom will be hard to maintain and results in ugly code (like mine or any of the solutions offered here).

Why not just give each select an unique id? It would make changing the value so much easier.

```
r[++j] = '</td><td><select id=profile-"'+data[i]+'"></select>';
```

Could then be changed with

```
$("#profile-Monday")
```

Comment: Hmm..there was some great reason why I didn't give each one unique id but can't remember it anymore. Can't be that good reason if I can't remember it anymore. I have now updated my code to use id on selectors and then just setting the value using it like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how the traversal functions of jQuery work.

- `children` traverses children
- `find` traverses children recursively
- `next` and `prev` traverse one sibling

You can't traverse both children and siblings at the same time.

In your case, you need to traverse siblings:

```
mondayTD.next('td')
```

now you reached the correct `td`, and you can traverse children:

```
.find('select')
```

Or (because the `select` is a child of `td`)

```
.children('select')
```

And you have your select.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working with this. Yeah..I really should read the docs better :)

Answer (score 2):

The selector you have to get the value of the `select` is incorrect: try this:

```
$('#TableWeeklyFrame tr.WeeklyFrameTR')
    .find('td.WeeklyFrameDay:contains("Monday")')
    .next('td').find('select.SelectionWeeklyFrameProfile').val()
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EGm3v/2/)

You may also want to look into using [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and how they can help you with this as they will be much quicker than using the `:contains('text')` selector.

Comment: Isn't your example same as one of what I have already tried? Ah, fiddle had right one. I'll have a look at those index and eq methods when I have more time.

Comment: @Spitz You're right - sorry, I copied the wrong line of code into my answer. I've updated it. At least the fiddle was right :)